# CanActivate requesting a stream after NavigationEnd

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-services, angular-guards

I'm trying to build a SubscriptionGuard in Angular.
This Guard should check whether the user has paid or not for the subscription.

I'm having a weird issue. I'll show the code and will explain this after.

> subscription.guard.ts

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlTree } from '@angular/router';
import { UsersService } from '../services/users.service';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SubscriptionGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(
        private usersService: UsersService,
        private router: Router
    ) { }

    async canActivate(route: any, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<UrlTree> {
        const status = await this.usersService.userSubscriptionStatus();
        let tree = this.router.parseUrl(state.url);

        // User should update payment methods.
        if (
            status === 'past_due' ||
            status === 'unpaid' ||
            status === 'incomplete'
        ) {
            tree = this.router.parseUrl('/subscription');
            tree.queryParams.subscriptionReturnUrl = state.url;
        }

        // User should create a new subscription.
        if (
            status === 'canceled' ||
            status === 'incomplete_expired' ||
            status === null
        ) {
            tree = this.router.parseUrl('/subscription');
            tree.queryParams.subReturnUrl = state.url;
            tree.queryParams.firstSub = status === null;
        }

        return tree;
    }
}
```

> users.service.ts

```js
// [ ... ]

async userSubscriptionStatus(): Promise<USS_Status | null> {
  const uid = (await this.getCurrentFire())?.uid;
  if (!uid) return null;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.db.colWithIds$<UserStripeSubscription>(
      `users/${uid}/subscriptions`,
      (ref: any) => ref.orderBy('created', 'desc')
    )
      .pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe((subs: UserStripeSubscription[]) => {
        let timestamp: number | null = null;
        let status: string | null = null;
        subs.forEach(sub => {
          if (!sub.status) return;
          if (!timestamp) {
            timestamp = sub.created.seconds;
            status = sub.status;
            return;
          }
          if (timestamp <= sub.created.seconds) {
            timestamp = sub.created.seconds;
            status = sub.status;
            return;
          }
          return;
        });
        console.log('status =>', status);
        resolve(status);
      });
  });
}

// [ ... ]
```

As you can see, the guard relies on the method `userSubscriptionStatus()` in `users.service.ts`.

In a first testing phase I was thinking that `.pipe(take(1))` wasn't working for some weird reason, but with a closer debugging I noticed that the problem was in fact that SubscriptionGuard was calling continuously the method in UsersService.

I tried everything but I don't know how to fix this.
This is what I'm getting in the console:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3p2I.png

Can someone help? I really don't know...

**[UPDATE #1]**
I updated the code. Now it's looking like this:

> subscription.guard.ts

```js
import { USS_Status } from './../models/user-stripe-subscription.model';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlTree } from '@angular/router';
import { UsersService } from '../services/users.service';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SubscriptionGuard implements CanActivate {

    private status: USS_Status | null | undefined = undefined;

    constructor(
        private usersService: UsersService,
        private router: Router
    ) { }

    canActivate(route: any, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<UrlTree> {
        return new Promise<UrlTree>((resolve, reject) => {
            const method = () => {
                let tree = this.router.parseUrl(state.url);

                if (
                    this.status === 'past_due' ||
                    this.status === 'unpaid' ||
                    this.status === 'incomplete'
                ) {
                    tree = this.router.parseUrl('/subscription');
                    tree.queryParams.subscriptionReturnUrl = state.url;
                }

                else if (
                    this.status === 'canceled' ||
                    this.status === 'incomplete_expired' ||
                    this.status === null
                ) {
                    tree = this.router.parseUrl('/subscription');
                    tree.queryParams.subReturnUrl = state.url;
                    tree.queryParams.firstSub = this.status === null;
                    console.log('...........................................');
                    console.log('this.status === null', this.status === null, this.status);
                    console.log('this.status === canceled', this.status === 'canceled', this.status);
                    console.log('this.status === incomplete_expired', this.status === 'incomplete_expired', this.status);
                }

                resolve(tree);
            };

            if (this.status === undefined)
                this.usersService.userSubscriptionStatus().then((status) => {
                    this.status = status;
                    method();
                    console.log('Guard status is =>', status);
                });
            else method();
        });
    }
}
```

> users.service.ts

```js
// [...]

async userSubscriptionStatus(): Promise<USS_Status | null> {
  const uid = (await this.getCurrentFire())?.uid;
  if (!uid) return null;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.db.colWithIds$<UserStripeSubscription>(
      `users/${uid}/subscriptions`,
      (ref: any) => ref.orderBy('created', 'desc')
    )
      .pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe((subs: UserStripeSubscription[]) => {
        let timestamp: number | null = null;
        let status: string | null = null;
        console.log('SUBS are => ', subs);
        subs.forEach(sub => {
          if (!sub.status) return;
          if (!timestamp) {
            timestamp = sub.created.seconds;
            status = sub.status;
            return;
          }
          if (timestamp <= sub.created.seconds) {
            timestamp = sub.created.seconds;
            status = sub.status;
            return;
          }
          return;
        });
        console.log('status =>', status);
        resolve(status);
      });
  });
}

// [...]
```

My console now look like this...

```
........................................... // subscription.guard.ts
'this.status === null' true null // subscription.guard.ts
'this.status === canceled' false null // subscription.guard.ts
'this.status === incomplete_expired' false null // subscription.guard.ts
'Guard status is =>' null // subscription.guard.ts

[WDS] Live Reloading enabled. // ANGULAR

'SUBS are =>' (2) [{…}, {…}] // users.service.ts
'status =>' 'active' // users.service.ts

........................................... // subscription.guard.ts
'this.status === null' true null // subscription.guard.ts
'this.status === canceled' false null // subscription.guard.ts
'this.status === incomplete_expired' false null // subscription.guard.ts
```

It seems that the service is running only AFTER the guard. I really don't know how to do it...

Comment: did you register the UserService class in app.module providers: [UsersService] ??

Comment: Nope. It wasn't registered. I just try, but I get same result in the console. UsersService is executed after the guard.

Comment: @Bharath I also tried to put the function that it's in the service, directly in the guard, but still doesn't work. The CanActivate method seems to not be compatible as async. But that's weird.. really weird... I'm missing something.

Comment: Hello @Bharath ? Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From console log output it is clear your userService is running first

Updated your code with `method` function accepting a parameter `statusParam`

```
canActivate(route: any, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<UrlTree> {
        return new Promise<UrlTree>((resolve, reject) => {
            const method = (statusParam) => {
                let tree = this.router.parseUrl(state.url);

                if (
                    statusParam === 'past_due' ||
                    statusParam === 'unpaid' ||
                    tstatusParam === 'incomplete'
                ) {
                    tree = this.router.parseUrl('/subscription');
                    tree.queryParams.subscriptionReturnUrl = state.url;
                }

                else if (
                    statusParam === 'canceled' ||
                    statusParam === 'incomplete_expired' ||
                    statusParam === null
                ) {
                    tree = this.router.parseUrl('/subscription');
                    tree.queryParams.subReturnUrl = state.url;
                    tree.queryParams.firstSub = statusParam === null;
                    console.log('...........................................');
                    console.log('statusParam === null', statusParam === null, statusParam);
                    console.log('statusParam === canceled', statusParam === 'canceled', statusParam);
                    console.log('statusParam === incomplete_expired', statusParam === 'incomplete_expired', statusParam);
                }

                resolve(tree);
            };

            if (this.status === undefined)
                this.usersService.userSubscriptionStatus().then((status) => {
                    // this.status = status;
                    console.log('Resolved Guard status is =>', status);
                    method(status);                    
                    console.log('Guard status is =>', status);
                });
            else method(this.status);
        });
    }
```